# Too few arguments to function error? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have no idea why the this code isn't working, Any help would be appreciated. no matter what I do I still get the same error. I know that there needs to be more arguments passed, but I just don't see what I could add.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
double getSales();
void findHighest(double sale[]);
int main()
{
 double sales;
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
 double salesNE, salesSE, salesNW, salesSW;
 double highest = 0;
 string winner;
 string names[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"Northeast", "Southeast", "Northwest", "Southwest"};
 double sale[ARRAY_SIZE];
 int counter = 0;
 cout<<"Input data for the Northeast Division:"<<endl;
 sale[0] = getSales();
 cout<<"Input data for the Southeast Division:"<<endl;
 sale[1] = getSales();
 cout<<"Input data for the Northwest Division:"<<endl;
 sale[2] = getSales(); 
 cout<<"Input data for the Southwest Division:"<<endl;
 sale[3] = getSales();
 findHighest();
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

double getSales()
{
 double sales;
 validate:
 cout<<"Enter the quaterly sales figures for this division:"<<endl;
 cin>>sales;
 if (sales < 0)
 {
  system("CLS");
  cout<<"Invalid input: sales figures must be higher than $0.00"<<endl;
  goto validate;
 }
 return sales;
}

void findHighest(double sale[])
{
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
 double highest = 0;
 int counter = 0;
 string winner;
 string names[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"Northeast", "Southeast", "Northwest", "Southwest"};
 while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
 if (sale[counter] > highest)
  {
   highest = sale[counter];
   winner = names[counter];
  }
  counter += 1;
 }
 cout<<"The "<<winner<<" division had the highest grossing sales at $"<<highest<<"."    <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: Please don't create puzzles unnecessarily. You need to say what line of code generates the error. Withholding useful information just wastes everybody's time. Also, have you considered that the problem is that there are too few arguments to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function argument is missing** in findHighest() function.

The function deceleration  is `void findHighest(double sale[]);`

You are not supplying argument  `double sale[]`

Thus replace the line  `findHighest()` [*the line before  system("PAUSE") statement* ]with  `findHighest(sale)`

Comment: Thank you for clearly defining what line the error was in.

Comment: Welcome.:) :) Also if the answer was useful to you, then please do not forget to tick(accept), so that it can help the future visitors at Stack Overflow Community:)

Answer (score 1):

Your function call:

```
findHighest();
```

Your function declaration:

```
void findHighest(double sale[]);
```

Seeing these does the ***"Too few arguments to function"*** error make sense? The error is pretty much self explanatory..Yes??